# How can I add targets, in addition to a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to add the target attribute to the following function, but with the tips go wrong, how can I do?
This and education source

```
ch ($links as $link) {
        $output .= "<li><a href='http://localhost/player/index.php?var=" . $link['link'] . "'>" . $link['name'] . "</a><br/></li>\n " ;
```

I would need to add the target after the link, but with continuous quotes in receiving error

```
ch ($links as $link) {
    $output .= "<li><a href='http://localhost/player/index.php?var=" . $link['link'] . "'>target="principale"" . $link['name'] . "</a><br/></li>\n " ;
```

Comment: Does your first code piece work?

Comment: The second script looks to have some issues with the quote characters around principale -- they'd break the string literal you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output .= "<li><a href='http://localhost/player/index.php?var=" . $link['link'] . "' target='principale'>" . $link['name'] . "</a><br/></li>\n "
```

1) use single quotes to avoid your quoting issue

2) make sure the target attribute is inside the  tag